# On the difference between the main effect in a one-factor and a two-factor regression

Tags: statistics, examples-counterexamples, statistical-inference, upper-lower-bounds, regression-analysis

*This question was asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) where it received little attention and no comments or answers, but as it is purely mathematically oriented it may well be more suitable here.*

---

Consider a linear regression (based on least squares) on two predictors including an interaction term: $$Y=(b_0+b_1X_1)+(b_2+b_3X_1)X_2$$

$b_2$ here corresponds to the *conditional effect* of $X_2$ when $X_1=0$. A common mistake  is to understand $b_2$ as being the *main effect* of $X_2$, i.e. the average effect of $X_2$ over all possible values of $X_1$.

Now let's assume that $X_1$ was centered, that is $\overline{X_1}=0$. It becomes now true that $b_2$ is the average effect of $X_2$ over all possible values of $X_1$, in the sense that $\overline{b_2+b_3X_1}=b_2$. In such conditions, the meaning given to $b_2$ is nearly indistinguishable from the meaning that we would give to the effect of $X_2$ in a simple regression (where $X_2$ would be the only factor, let's call this effect $B_2$).

In practice, it seems that $b_2$ and $B_2$ are reasonably close to each other.

> **Are there any "common knowledge" examples of situations where $B_2$ and $b_2$ are remarkably far from each other?**
>
> **Are there any known upper bounds to $|b_2-B_2|$?**